# Database text not styling

Tags: php, html, css

I'm outputting database information that contains code such as `<b>` or `<u>` or `<i>` but the text isn't styling. I'm using `nlbr()` to format it correctly and `htmlspecialchars()` when inputting `textarea` text into a database if that helps.

What am I missing?

Comment: It might be a typo but it is nl2br()

Comment: What do you mean by 'text isn't styling'? Are you seeing the html elements i.e. <u> instead of the text being underlined?

Comment: a small screen shot will be helpful

Comment: Yes jeff. I'm seeing <u> and <b> instead of styling.

Comment: You need to convert them back: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars-decode.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the input string passed to this function and the final document share the same character set, this function is sufficient to prepare input for inclusion in most contexts of an HTML document. If, however, the input can represent characters that are not coded in the final document character set and you wish to retain those characters (as numeric or named entities), both this function and htmlentities() (which only encodes substrings that have named entity equivalents) may be insufficient. You may have to use mb_encode_numericentity() instead.

htmlspecialchars — Convert special characters to HTML entities

**htmlentities — Convert all applicable characters to HTML entities**

http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php